# Capistrano deployment does not copy config/environments/*.rb files to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I am trying to deploy a multi environment/multi stage rails 4 project to different servers using Capistrano 3.4.

I have all files in `config/environments/<environment>.rb` in my git repository, and then use the `config/secrets.yml` for things which should not be in git.

However, when I deploy, the `config/environments/` directory does not exists.

I can add the environment file as a linked file, and store it in the shared directory. But I want to use the version directly from git.

E.g.

`set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml config/environments/production.rb}`

So, How can I tell Capistrano to include all the files from `config/environments/` into the deployment?

UPDATE:

My `deploy/production.rb`look like this

```
set :branch, 'master'
set :env, 'production'
set :rails_env, fetch(:env)

server 'prod-server.domain.tld',
       user: 'deploy',
       roles: %w{web app db}

set :deploy_to, "/u/apps/my_app_#{fetch(:env)}"

# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, true

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml config/secrets.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system cache}

namespace :deploy do

    after :updated, :cleanup # clean up assets
    before :compile_assets, :migrate # migrate db
    before :published, :compile_assets # compile new assets

end
```

And when deploying, I actually get this error multiple times

`config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:`

But the config is set in the different environments files, they are just not copied.

Comment: Can you post the results of `git status --ignored`? Just to ensure that files in `config/environments/` are not ignored

Comment: The git status --ignores does not show the environment files - they are included in the git repository.

Comment: where does the `config/environments` not exist? in the current release path?

Comment: Yes. In the current path. All other config-files in config/ does exists on the deployment server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found the problem. A developer had added this line to the `.gitattributes`.

```
config/environments/ export-ignore
```

So when capistrano did the archive to deploy, the files was not included.

Answer (score 1):

Capistrano does nothing by default to skip config/environments directory, so if you did not add it to .gitignore (and it is in the repo), and you have not added it to "linked_dirs", then it should be pulled from the repo just like any other file/directory.

Comment: Yes, but somehow its not working in my project. I have added my deploy/production.rb as example in the question.